# JavaScript Pitfall/Pattern Name

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

What is the proper name of the following pitfall? I see a lit of people make this mistake, so I'd like to be able to refer to it by name:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i ++) {
   imgs[i].someFunc = function() {
      // var i not a closure variable
      console.log(imgs[i]);
   };
}
```

Comment: “Closure misunderstanding”

Comment: I don't know if has a canonical name, but here's the SO question to refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I'll go with "closure misunderstanding" :-) but I'm afraid there'd be ambiguities involved... Where's Martin Fowler or Doug Crockford when we need them?!